# com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: unexpected XML tag. expected: {}processResponse but found: {}process

Tags: java, xml, soap

I am consuming a vendor web service. Generated the classes using javax.xml.ws for the vendor WSDL. Now I am trying to invoke the web service using a simple java client class and getting this exception with the response.

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException:
    unexpected XML tag. expected: {urn:cbv2}executeResponse but found:
    {urn:cbv2}execute   at
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.verifyTag(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:261)
    ~[na:1.8.0_191]     at
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.verifyTag(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:266)
    ~[na:1.8.0_191]     at
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$DocLit.readResponse(ResponseBuilder.java:634)
    ~[na:1.8.0_191]     at
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:243)
    ~[na:1.8.0_191]     at
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:189)
    ~[na:1.8.0_191]     at
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:276)
    ~[na:1.8.0_191]     at
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:104)
    ~[na:1.8.0_191]     at
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
    ~[na:1.8.0_191]     at
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
    ~[na:1.8.0_191]
```

I am calling the web service by following code:

```
String response = xyz.execute(xmlContent);
```

The class file is:

```
@WebService(name = "xyz", targetNamespace =
"http://localhost/cbv2.wsdl") @XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class }) public interface xyz {


    /**
     * Service definition of function cbv2__execute
     * 
     * @param in
     * @retcxz
     *     retcxzs java.lang.String
     */
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "out", targetNamespace = "cxz:cbv2")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "execute", targetNamespace = "cxz:cbv2", className = "cbv2.execute")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "executeResponse", targetNamespace = "cxz:cbv2", className = "cbv2.executeResponse")
    public String execute(
        @WebParam(name = "in", targetNamespace = "cxz:cbv2")
        String in);

}
```

Can anyone please help?